# DNN accuracy drop half way through training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am training a simple 2 layer hidden net with 10 dimensional hidden layers.  The accuracy improves until epoch 14 when it drops to be half as good.  What would cause this and how can I fix it? I was thinking it could be something to do with vanishing gradients, but it is such a small net that i'm not sure...

I made the plot bellow to show the relation between depth and width in a DNN.  I dont seem to se a pattern in when it fails.

[depth-vs-width graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmeGp.png)

`| epoch | val_acc             | val_loss            |
|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 0     | 0.87280000000000002 | 0.4549577592611313  |
| 1     | 0.9042              | 0.33785744296908377 |
| 2     | 0.90439999999999998 | 0.32197892428636549 |
| 3     | 0.9204              | 0.28751977597177031 |
| 4     | 0.92400000000000004 | 0.27027705881893632 |
| 5     | 0.92090000000000005 | 0.27390556887090206 |
| 6     | 0.92430000000000001 | 0.27321851629316807 |
| 7     | 0.92559999999999998 | 0.26133619344234466 |
| 8     | 0.92800000000000005 | 0.25024868482649326 |
| 9     | 0.9284              | 0.24917590338289738 |
| 10    | 0.92930000000000001 | 0.25116596995443108 |
| 11    | 0.92730000000000001 | 0.25142454357892274 |
| 12    | 0.93100000000000005 | 0.24925820100381971 |
| 13    | 0.90459999999999996 | 0.32235068403929473 |
| 14    | 0.49480000000000002 | 7.9964268966674803  |
| 15    | 0.48849999999999999 | 8.1361763145446773  |
| 16    | 0.37880000000000003 | 9.9022711822509759  |`

I am using keras as a framework with the code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim=10)
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=10)
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=10)
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=(mnist.test.images, mnist.test`.labels), callbacks=callback_list)
```

Comment: Is this happening all the time? Have you tried to restart training or keep training process going on to check the further training

Comment: I have tried multiple times and it seems to fail 3/4 attempts.  When I let it go further it always drops to an accuracy equivalent to random guessing.

Comment: Have you tried dropout or other refularization method? How about training loss and accuracy. Maybe it's due to overfitting.

Comment: Good suggestions.  The train loss and accuracy are comparable so it is not overfitting... Im experimenting without adding those techniques to get a baseline, and I don't think they would help with this problem.  All I do is initialize the weights with He Normal initialization.